# He had gone 84 days now without taking a fish and 30 days to school

Tags: grammar

A sentence in the novella *The Old Man and the Sea* goes

> He was an old man who fished alone in a skiff in the Gulf Stream and **he had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish**.

A sentence built with "he had gone" and then a period has brought me questions.

As far as I know, "go" roughly means "move in time or space" and usually is intransitve. Is it ok to alter the sentence with an extra "for" into "he had gone for eighty-four days now without taking a fish".

Or, is it the best to  maintain the status quo without the preposition? I guess so as I am not a poet or native. By that logic, is it appropriate to make a sentence like **"I have gone 30 days to school"?**

Comment: *eighty-four days* is a time noun phrase but it functions as an adverb. e.g. "It went **five days** without stopping"; "I'll see you Monday". This is quite common in English. Distance noun phrases can work the same way -- "It went **five kilometers** without stopping"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the primary meaning of *go* is to do with movement, but one of the definitions supplied by Oxford Languages is *pass a specified amount of time in a particular way* and the example they give is "I went a year without seeing my kids".

This usage doesn't really work with your sentence, because *go to school* normally has the other meaning of the verb - 'travel to school' or 'attend school'.

Comment: To add to this, I think "I have gone X days" is generally used with specific constructions, such as "I have gone X days without..." but not "I have gone X days to..." It's not the usual way of expressing time in English: "I have waited X days" or "I have been doing something for X days" would be more usual.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Still, the cloest definitions to one you provided I've got in Oxford Learner's Dictionaries -as I got no access to Oxford Languages- are "used to talk about how quickly or slowly time seems to pass" and "to spend a period of time in a particular way". I've also got two related sentences: they are "Hasn't the time gone quickly?" and "They went for two weeks without receiving any news.". The latter includes "for". Is it necessary or optional? To provide another example, I went 30 days without going to school. Is it fair?

Comment: If you google '[word] definition', the first result to come up should be from Oxford Languages. The second of your two Oxford Learner's definitions is almost the same as the one I referred to. Yes, the 'for' is optional.

Comment: On top of "go", the way of GOogling is also amazing. As a digital native, I feel a bit ashamed. Thank you again, Kate. I am Kitty anyway.